# Deploying a Django application to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy `myapp` to Heroku. I followed the documentation, but am now running into this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
login_home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://myapp.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
login_home.html
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 136
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 29 Jan 2015 14:24:21 -0500
```

The settings tell me my templates can be found at `/myapp/static/templates/` which is correct locally.

I've seen several posts about similar issues, but none have resolved my issue.

Please help!

erip

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant parts of my `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "myapp", "static", "templates"),
)
```

Comment: Please show the TEMPLATE_DIRS part of your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I've stopped using Heroku, but I had a quick look at a project I know I hosted there once. I remember that using [the path.py module](https://pythonhosted.org/path.py/index.html) solved a lot of issues with filesystem related stuff.

For what it's worth, these were my settings related to templates:

```
from path import Path
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).abspath().dirname().dirname()

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT / 'templates',
)
```

Give it a try, I'd say.

Comment: This didn't work. I noticed that within the debug page that django gives, it says that `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is `('/myapp/static/templates',)`

Might the first `/` cause problems when pushed to Heroku?

Comment: It might indeed...Try hardcoding the TEMPLATE_DIRS value and test from there.

Comment: I tried hardcoding, but it didn't work. This is super frustrating.

Comment: Perhaps [this Heroku Django template](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template) can shed some light on the matter?